# Unix command to send mail having subject from a variable

Tags: mailx

We have created a UNIX program which is used to send mails. In that program we are fetching the mail subject and body based on user inputs (through Oracle Concurrent Program)

For example:

The complete user inputs of concurrent program are storing in `$1` variable which is as below:

```
XX_EMAIL_FILES FCP_REQID=9614696 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/sup12" \
FCP_USERID=5667 \
FCP_USERNAME="SRI" \
FCP_PRINTER="noprint" \
FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y \
FCP_NUM_COPIES=1 \
"9614556_SUP12_XX_Workflow_Stuck_AP_Invoices.csv" \
"/tmp_mnt2/attachments" \
"Sri.B@xx.com" \
"This is the subject for the mail" \
"PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow."
```

Here, subject for mail is ***`This is the subject for the mail`*** which we are storing in variable **`SUB`** and body for mail is ***`PFA for the list of Invoices that are stuck in workflow.`*** which we are storing in another variable **`FCP_BODY`**.

Now, I wrote as below to send mail

```
echo "Hello,
${FCP_BODY}
Thanks,
Bommi
"| mailx -s $SUB
```

But, in the mail I received, the body is coming properly, but subject is coming just ***`This`***.

Can anyone please help me on how to fetch the complete subject to send mail?

Comment: Since `$SUB` variable contains multiple words you should quote the variable with `| mailx -s "$SUB"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: also, if you are sending attachments in the message (e.g. a .CSV file), you probably want to use a tool that knows how to do mime attachments correctly, rather than `mailx`.  e.g. [mime-construct](http://www.argon.org/~roderick/) - this is available packaged for debian, and probably other distros too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the variable `$SUB`:

```
... mailx -s "$SUB"
```

---

Explanation: A variable containing spaces is going to be subject to *word splitting*. That is, if you have the command

```
mailx -s $SUB
```

and the variable `$SUB` contains the string *`"This is the subject for the mail"`*

the previous command gets expanded as

```
mailx -s This is the subject for the mail
```

i.e. the `-s` flag (Subject) gets only the argument *`This`*, and the rest of the words are passed as other arguments, and (in most cases) handled like garbage.

Instead,

```
mailx -s "$SUB"
```

gets expanded as

```
mailx -s "This is the subject for the mail"
```

which is what you wanted.

---

Related questions and answers:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Hi,

Thank you :) It really helped and resolved the issue 

Regards,